# Android Drag and Expand View

Tags: android, android-layout, draggable, android-view, expand

I need to implement something similar to Android's notification bar. I would like to make a view that the user can drag and expand. The part that is not visible at the bigining has more views. (The image below explain what I want to achieve).

[image]

Comment: Hey @Stanete have you done expanding view on dragging the item or cardView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sliding drawer i know its deprecated but still works well even in android 4.4 have a look at this [tutorial](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/slidingdrawer.php) for sliding drawer

Comment: Ohh that looks pretty nice. If it is deprecated, that means it will stop working at some point?

Comment: i don't think so i have used it in my application also and its working so you don't need to worry you can find many methods that are deprecated but still working so go ahead and try it

Comment: Thank you. So I'll try this on my app.

Comment: When we tap on the provided link, it's opening a new site every time ;)